# Fixed SVG Layer Position on Open Layers Map

Tags: svg, openlayers

I have a map with multiple Layers. One of them shall project an SVG on the map, indicating certain regions (if not obvious, it's the red area in the images). I got this working on the default zoom level.

[image]

But as soon as I change the zoom in any direction, the SVG layer just moves too much in a direction depending on where I initiate the zoom change.

[image]

This is the relevant code I have:

```
//Map init
    var mapcenter = ol.proj.fromLonLat([10.615219, 51.799502]);
    var layers = [];
    var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.OSM()
            })
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
            center: mapcenter,
            zoom: 9.5
        })
    });

//SVG init
    const svgContainer = document.createElement('div');
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', '/shared/harzregionen.svg');
    xhr.addEventListener('load', function () {
      const svg = xhr.responseXML.documentElement;
      svgContainer.ownerDocument.importNode(svg);
      svgContainer.appendChild(svg);
    });
    xhr.send();

    const width = 350;
    const height = 0;
    const svgResolution = 360 / width;
    svgContainer.style.width = width + 'px';
    svgContainer.style.height = height + 'px';
    svgContainer.className = 'svg-layer';

//SVG Layer
    map.addLayer(
        new ol.layer.Vector({
            render: function (frameState) {
                const scale = svgResolution / frameState.viewState.resolution;
                const center = frameState.viewState.center;
                const size = frameState.size;
                const cssTransform = ol.transform.composeCssTransform(
                    300,
                    120,
                    480 / frameState.viewState.resolution,
                    480 / frameState.viewState.resolution,
                    frameState.viewState.rotation,
                    -(center[0] - mapcenter[0]) / 420, //These values were kinda
                    (center[1] - mapcenter[1]) / 250 //trial and error for default zoom
                );
                svgContainer.style.transform = cssTransform;
                svgContainer.style.opacity = this.getOpacity();
                return svgContainer;
            }
        })
    );
```

I'm pretty sure I have to use a certain formula to calculate the values in `composeCssTransform` but it feels like there *should* be an easy way to do it instead of trial and error until it somewhat works.

So, my question is: Is there an easy way to lock an SVG layer to a set position on the world map like the layers with markers?

Comment: You should not need to guess the width and height of the image, it is a property of the image.  But you will need to estimate its extent in the view projection as accurately as possible.  Since the extent is not centered on [0, 0] you need to use the difference between view center and extent center in the transform. https://codesandbox.io/s/svg-layer-forked-qgmxx6?file=/main.js

Comment: @Mike I didn't know about the correct usage of Extent (and even now I can't find much useful information in the OL docs) but this did the trick, thank you! When you put your comment into an answer, I'll gladly mark this as answered!